# What is actually happening when we loading a tensorflow graph?

Tags: tensorflow

What is meant by the loading all  operations in to the graph before evaluate them with a session.run().What I have see in even in the graph construction process tf goes inside the functions and load them in to some stack as object. So it's not only their location.